# I want to designate folder to store google images

Tags: python, path, urlretrieve

> urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgUrl, image_name + "_" + str(count+1) + ".jpg")
>
> ## google images are always saved the same folder as where source code is

every time I want to change folders to save them

> import os
> import tkinter.ttk as ttk
> import tkinter.messagebox as msgbox
> from tkinter import *
> from tkinter import filedialog
> from PIL import Image
>
> root = Tk()>
> root.title("Nado GUI")>
>
> def keyword():
> value = keyword_entry.get()
> return value
>
> def number():
> image_number = number_entry.get()
> return image_number
>
> def google_image():
>
> ```
> from selenium import webdriver
> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
> import time
> import urllib.request
>
> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
> driver.get("https://www.google.co.kr/imghp?hl=ko&tab=wi&authuser=0&ogbl")
> elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
>
> elem.send_keys(keyword())
> elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
>
> images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".rg_i.Q4LuWd")
> count = 0
> for image in images:
>     try:
>         image.click()
>         time.sleep(1)
>         imgUrl = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/c-wiz/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/c-wiz/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/a/img').get_attribute("src")
>         opener=urllib.request.build_opener()
>         opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1941.0 Safari/537.36')]
>         urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
>         
>         image_name = keyword_entry.get() 
>                 
>         urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgUrl, image_name + "_" + str(count+1) + ".jpg")
>         count = count + 1
>         limit = number_entry.get()
>         if count >= int(limit):
>             break
>     except:
>         pass
>
> driver.close()
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding the path to the image name:

```
 urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgUrl, "/folder/" + image_name + "_" + str(count+1) + ".jpg")
```

You may have to adjust your string for your OS and Path. but this works for me:

```py
url = f'{URL_TO_IMAGE}/{IMAGE_NAME}.jpg'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "./folder/" + "image_name" + ".jpg")
```

[image]

Comment: adding the path to the image name doesn't work